# How to change the background image of second monitor without connecting to it?

Tags: terminal, display, desktop, spaces

Is there a way to change the background image of the second monitor without connecting the Mac to it?

I connected my Macbook to a projector and set up a background image. Now that I disconnected the projector, is there a way to change the background image before connecting the projector again? 
The reason for this is simple: I need a way to define a single background image on all spaces, monitors and projectors at once so I know which background image my audience will see when I connect to a projector or change to another space. I just want one way to change all desktop backgrounds at once, even displays that are not connected.
I would prefer a Terminal command so I can script this.

Comment: What version of OS X/macOS are you running?

Comment: I am using macOS 10.13.2 (High Sierra)